# CSS media query not executing max-width

Tags: html, css

I am adjusting the page width in chrome, inspect>toggle device toolbar.

when the width is less than 600 it does not display the button for some reason. Can anybody spot what's wrong with this?

thanks in advance

```css
.login-button {
  font-size: 21px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 8px 10px;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .login-button {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="login-button">
  <span><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Button</span>
</button>
```

Comment: You need to specify if it is print or screen etc

Comment: post the related HTML code.

Comment: Are you sure that icon library is loaded (i.e. the icons that are displayed using the `fas login`class)? Because otherwise there is no content, no background, no border --> invisible.

Comment: Yes, if i load it display: initial in the main css snippet it shows the icon, however it doesnt work when the screen is adjusted and the code reversed etc.

Comment: is there potentially another way to make it responsive?

Comment: Your code works fine for me as is; I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
 .login-button{
   font-size: 21px;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   margin: 8px 10px;
   visibility: hidden;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .login-button {
        visibility: visible;
        font-size: 21px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin: 8px 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it, doesn't fix, unfortunately. Thanks though!

Comment: "visible" isn't a valid value for `display`. And putting the media query before the general rule will make the general rule overwrite the media query.

Comment: still not displaying the button when screen is changed. I am in chrome adjusting the size in the inspect > toggle device toolbar. and resizing there. could the issue be there?

Comment: Can you link me to the page by chance? I have tested the CSS & HTML in JSFiddle & everything seems to be working properly, which leads me to believe there's a different cause.

Comment: wow, i just ran it in jsfiddle as well and it works, i was running the page offline and testing it in chrome could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have missed the closing curly brace. I hope this solves the issue:

```
@media (max-width : 600px){
    .login-button {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey was a copy/paste mistake, still doesnt work. thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .login-button {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```